# Webdriver how to find the parent fieldset element of a given element using Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a HTML like the one below

```
<fieldset id='fs1'>
  <legend>Basic Details</legend>
  <div>
    <input type='text' id='txt1'/>
    <input type='text' id='txt2'/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I can get to the textboxes by saying

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txt1"));
```

Now, I want my webdriver to check if this textbox (or any other element at this stage) is the child of a fieldset. In other words, I want to find the parent "fieldset" tag of a given element.

And I need to use xpath and nothing else.

Now, I have tried using ("..") as my xpath query, which will return me the Div parent, and i have to keep doing it until I hit the fieldset. I just wonder if there is a straight forward solution.
Can anyone suggest an xpath query which will help me do what I have explained?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `ancestor::` [axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), which includes the parent, grandparent, etc. all the way up the tree.  In particular:

```
ancestor::fieldset[1]
```

will give you the nearest enclosing `fieldset` element ancestor for the current context element (or an empty node set if the context element isn't inside a `fieldset`).

Comment: Bingo!! Thank you @Ian Roberts

Answer (score 2):

One way is to search for `fieldset` and include a condition on children:

```
.//fieldset[.//input[@id="txt1"]]
```